# cmake does not find QtQuick even if it's installed

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qtquick2

I installed Qt 6.2.0 with the online installer and selected most of the module for Desktop development.
I get this strange message:

```
/home/user/Qt/Examples/Qt-6.2.0/multimedia/video/mediaplayer/CMakeLists.txt:28: error: Found package configuration file: /home/user/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package: Failed to find Qt component "Quick". Expected Config file at "/home/user/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Quick/Qt6QuickConfig.cmake" exists
```

English is not my primary language, and I'm not sure what the last sentence really means:

```
"Expected Config file at <path> exists"
```

Actually the file exists:

```
$ ls /home/user/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Quick/Qt6QuickConfig.cmake 
/home/user/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Quick/Qt6QuickConfig.cmake
```

I don't understand why it don't find QtQuick and then I don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 6):

I had to install the qt6-declarative-dev package for Qt Creator in Ubuntu to pick this up automatically. After that, it worked out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to find Qt component "Quick".

see the file `lib/cmake/Qt6Quick/Qt6QuickTargets.cmake`

the variable `_IMPORT_PREFIX` tells cmake
where to find the `include/` and `lib/` files for QtQuick

usually its the parent-parent-parent folder of the cmake file
so `/home/user/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64` in your case

for debugging, add this to `Qt6QuickTargets.cmake`

```
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
# ...

message("debug: _IMPORT_PREFIX = ${_IMPORT_PREFIX}")
```

the file `libQt6Quick.so` should be in the `_IMPORT_PREFIX` path

otherwise find it by

```sh
cd /home/user/Qt/6.2.0/gcc_64
find . -name 'libQt6Quick.so*'
```

related:
the environment variable `QT_ADDITIONAL_PACKAGES_PREFIX_PATH`
helps qt to find the `lib/cmake/Qt6(modulename)/Qt6(modulename)Targets.cmake` files